# Rajawali Nullpointer on md5

Tags: android, eclipse, rajawali

my first question here. I'm trying Rajawali engine, and it works great, but I'm having one error with an MD5 file.

I'm trying to replace the Bob md5 file with one of my own (with Bob works just fine), but I get this error:

```
12-15 16:40:13.226: E/AndroidRuntime(2651): FATAL EXCEPTION: GLThread 131232
12-15 16:40:13.226: E/AndroidRuntime(2651): Process: xxxxxxxxx, PID: 2651
12-15 16:40:13.226: E/AndroidRuntime(2651): java.lang.NullPointerException
12-15 16:40:13.226: E/AndroidRuntime(2651):     at xxxxxxxxx.Renderer.onDrawFrame(Renderer.java:97)
12-15 16:40:13.226: E/AndroidRuntime(2651):     at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.guardedRun(GLSurfaceView.java:1523)
12-15 16:40:13.226: E/AndroidRuntime(2651):     at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.run(GLSurfaceView.java:1240)
```

I'm guessing something wrong with my MD5 export.
The model was done in blender, exported with http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Extensions:2.6/Py/Scripts/Import-Export/IdTech4_md5

In modelviewer it works great, and the mesh is triangulated. I don't know if I'm missing something when exporting from blender.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I found my error. The material name and the texture file had different names, so the parser was looking for a file with the name of the material. Changed the material name and now it works!